# Cómo identificar un dato de MySQL con PHP o JS?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

esta es mi primer consulta sobre PHP.
Tengo un sitio web de avisos clasificados que funciona así:
En la página principal, usted despliega un menú para recorrer los rubros.
Cada rubro, para no tener una dirección (digamos pueloweb.com.ar/inmuebles y así) por cada uno, es cargado a través de una petición ajax que toma un documento fuera de la carpeta pública y con una función javascript lo "imprime" en el innerHTML de un elemento del index.
Cada uno de los documentos controladores de rubros, a su vez, se conectan a una base de datos, y con un ciclo foreach obtienen e imprimen todos los avisos que correspondan con su rubro.
Ahora, el problema es el siguiente.
Todos los avisos se imprimen en el index, pero a mi me gustaría que cada persona que envia su aviso (yo lo cargo a una base de datos de MySQL) pueda ver su aviso sin necesidad de buscarlo, es decir, poder responder algo así como: "Tu aviso ya está publicado, miralo acá: https://etc...".
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo sin necesidad de poner los rubros en la carpeta pública? Pasar una variable por algún lado? no sé qué hacer. muchas gracias

Comment: Lo que pides seria algo así como un "rubro" de "Mis Publicaciones", que (detectando el usuario) retorne la lista de publicaciones creadas por el usuario? Qué parte de eso no puedes hacer?, la identificación de usuario?, la relación usuario-publicación?
Porque el listado ya lo tienes dominado (no es distinto a las "paginas" que ya cargas con el Ajax, solo varia la consulta)

Comment: Los usuarios no se registran, son anonimos, sólo yo accedo a la base de datos. 
Una idea que se me habia ocurrido era forzar una URL con php header y que después el usuario ingrese a esa url especifica.
pueloweb.com.ar fijate como es el sitio

Comment: Ah, ya entendí, las publicaciones no tienen "pagina propia", digamos, no tienen una pantalla visualización independiente, solo existen en listados... y quieres utilizarlo por ajax? (para no variar la dirección, supongo), no es enteramente posible, la url debe contener la información, por lo tanto debe haber una pagina (direccion) que la tome, tras tomarla podría guardarla en el storage asociado a la conección (session_start(); $_SESSION['AvisoIDTemporal']=$_GET['Aviso']), redirigir a una pagina index que contenga la variable para que la tome ajax y haga la llamada para que cargue el innerHTML.

Comment: Gracias Ricardo

Answer (score 0):

A ver si lo que quieres es cargar un elemento en concreto teniendo un solo PHP hay formas de hacerlo.

La fea es con parámetro GET: miweb.com/?rubro=inmuebles

En este caso puedes obtener el valor con:

```
if (isset($_GET['rubro']) // si hay parámetro
{
    $rubroInicial = $_GET['rubro'];
    // Muestra directamente ese
}
```

Las URLs quedan un poco feas.

La forma "bonita" es obtener el parámetro de la ruta:
miweb.com/inmuebles

Esto **no** significa crear otro PHP aparte, sólo detectar si se ha escrito algo más en la URL. Esto sería más sencillo si usaras algún framework, pero en el caso de que estés usando simplemente el index.php:

```
$uriSegments = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
```

Y esto te dará toda la ruta como un array:

miweb.com/a/b/c  =>  [a, b, c]

Si la lista está vacía, cargas la web normal, si hay mínimo 1 elemento, es un rubro.

Comment: Hola Oscar, me tomo el atrevimiento de comentarte porque quizás el creador de esta pregunta jamás lo haga, él no quiere usar ni usa otra url del sitio que no sea la raíz, todo lo carga por ajax, y quiere un método para que la url "desemboque" una carga de ajax especifica (en la raiz de su sitio).

Comment: Buenas Ricardo, ya lo había entendido, y lo que comento permite hacer eso exactamente. Con un parámetro GET ( ?id=xxx ) haces exactamente eso, tienes una sola URL y le pasas un parámetro. Y con la segunda opción... tienes otra URL a nivel de SEO, pero sólo tienes un PHP index. No estás haciendo realmente 2 páginas, así que solo tienes una página en tu web. Cualquiera de los dos casos le sirve para lograr lo que quiere.